# Upon opening spotify the entire system freezes

Tags: 22.04, freeze, spotify

On Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64-bit if I open Spotify, installed from the store, the entire system freezes. REISUB doesn't work and I don't know at all what's happening. I don't know what's happening, so I may not be able to provide everything at once.

Specs:
RAM - 2x8GB DDR3,
cpu - AMD® Athlon(tm) x4 860k quad core processor × 4
, GPU - NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
, 1TB HDD

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add hardware specifications, particularly graphics.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I edited the question

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers? GTX750ti should run with the latest version. And if your system has UEFI then disable Secure Boot.

Comment: The drivers are the newest ones from nvidia, so that should be the problem, can you tell me how I can disable Secure Boot?

Comment: No, I can't tell you how to disable Secure Boot because it's firmware dependent. Please check the user's manual of your motherboard.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond, Secure boot is disabled from what I could see, or maybe U don't even have this option. What can I do?

Comment: Unless your system is from circa 2012 or newer -and- properly installed in UEFI mode then Secure Boot isn't applicable.

Comment: And, of course, Nvidia drivers should be installed by 1. selecting that option during Ubuntu installation; 2. *a posteriori* using additional drivers; NOT from the Nvidia binaries. Also, using those you'll have to repeat the installation for each newer kernel version. So, I strongly advise here to check Additional Drivers.to confirm the correct drivers are installed.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of didn't understand what you said here. I installed NVIDIA drivers by changing them in the settings. I don't know if there's another way.

Comment: That is the correct way.

Comment: So from what I understand, the solution might be to go to software and updates and install the newest version? Of propertiary drivers

Comment: At Software & Updates > Additional drivers it should show the recommend Nvidia (proprietary) version.

Comment: Right now I have nvidia-drivers-510 version, but if I try to change to the newer 515 version, it doesnt let me by showing me a popup with an x symbol, no error message. Also no drivers show up as recommended, all of them are "propertiary", with the 515 also being "tested". (ignoring X-org obviously)

Comment: Okay so my drivers are updated, but spotify still freezes my pc. What can I do, after reinstalling earlier I could at least get to login page, but after logging in it froze. Now it just freezes when opening spotify, leaving the window open.

Comment: It doesn't happen in any PC running Ubuntu 22.04 that Ive tested, regardless of the graphics. So, it must be something specific to yours.

Comment: That said, it giving an error with the newer version and knowing that 515.xx is the recommended version for your graphics it suggests there's a deeper problem indeed.

Comment: So after restarting my pc I could install the 515 version, (which is marked as tested) and it didn't solve the issue, spotify doesnt even show the log in screen. What else can I do?